# Connect PHP to JS function in loop element

Tags: javascript, php

**Below is my code**

```
HTML/PHP:
         <?php $nay = $row['id']; ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 header-admin below-admin" >
    <input class="password" id="<?php echo $nay; ?>" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $nay; ?>)" type="password" style="" value="<?php echo $xyz = $row['password']; ?>">
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
        var idMap;
      function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById("<?php echo $nay; ?>");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}
    </script>
```

**Desire Output:**

i want to connect the function to the onclick function by using ID but the problem i am facing is due to loop it is just working on the last value of the list whereas i want it to display to all the values displayed but it is not getting connected by the id.

Please help me with the connection of PHP and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made mistake in javascript code.
In this line `var x = document.getElementById(id);` you were using php code so it was printing last row's id in js function. But it should be dynamic and passed through event caller function only to make it dynamic.
Use this code snippet and it should work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(id) {
        var x = document.getElementById(id);
        if (x.type === "password") {
            x.type = "text";
        } else {
            x.type = "password";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what you have changed and why.

Answer (score -1):

In the value of password just used.

[image]

and in your onclick function just used.

```
onclick="myFunction(this.id)"
```